# Armature Root Bone in FBX Export

Tags: armature, export, bones, .fbx

I've seen several posts on this topic, but I fear they are old and forgotten, so I decided to post a new one.

I've been working around the armature being exported as the exterior-most bone in FBX files by importing to Maya, deleting the armature, and adding a root there before importing into UE4/Mixamo.

My question is whether anybody knows a way to avoid using Maya as a middle-man, because it just complicates the process for me.

Comment: Note: Using the Armature as the root for root-motion in UE4 does not work because there is unexpected rotation.